# How to change the position static to fixed when the bottom of specific section is reached

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just started learning jQuery and JS and I'm now having difficulties making some basic stuff.

I want to make the static navigation bar become fixed when the window reaches the end of the `.hero-fullscreen` section and goes back to static if not.

```js
$(window).on("scroll", function() {

  var navbar = $(".navbar");
  if (navbar.offset().top > 150) {
    navbar.addClass(".navbar-fixed");
  } else {
    navbar.removeClass(".navbar-fixed");
  }

});
```

```css
.navbar {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
}

.navbar-static {
  position: static;
}

.navbar-fixed {
  position: fixed;
}

.hero-fullscreen {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.random-section {
  height: 100vh; 
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-static"></nav>
<section class="hero-fullscreen bg-image"></section>
<section class="random-section"></section>
```

Now, my question is, instead of `.top > 150`, what should be there so the `navbar` becomes fixed when it reaches the bottom of the `.hero-fullscreen` (the red one) section?

Thank you!

Comment: FYI your HTML is missing some closing quotes on the `class` attributes

Comment: i would be able to answer this question a LOT quicker if you included a codepen or jsfiddle. also, i'm pretty sure your code snippet is broken

Comment: Thank you guys for pointing me this out, I fixed the code, snippet shows well now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to do two things:

1. Find out the height of the viewport
2. Always keep track of where the
   scrollbar is

## Like so

```
    window.addEventListener('load', getWindowHeight);
    window.addEventListener('resize', getWindowHeight);

    var endPos;

    function getWindowHeight(){
      var hei = window.innerHeight;
      endPos = hei + 50;
    }

    document.addEventListener('scroll', trackScroll);

    var navBar = document.getElementById('navbar');

    function trackScroll() {
      var scrollPos = document.body.scrollTop();
      if (scrollPos > endPos) {
        navBar.style.position = 'fixed';
      } else {
        navBar.style.position = 'static';
      }
    }
```

However, I've made it so that you'll have to give your navigation element an `id` of `navbar`, not a `class`.

1. `getWindowHeight` fulfills the first requirement.
2. `trackScroll` fulfills the second requirement and makes the necessary changes.